# Ag-grid editing group in data-tree server side mode

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

**PROBLEM:**

In Server Side Data-Tree mode cells in group rows is not editable. I based on this documentation for building the grid - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-tree-data .Example:

> https://plnkr.co/edit/t1uZ4V3cUs6IHZDsPKYI?p=preview

In this example group rows is not editable, in spite of all columns have 'editable: true' properties

```
this.columnDefs = [
              { field: "jobTitle", editable: true },
              { field: "employmentType", editable: true }
        ];
        this.defaultColDef = {
          width: 240,
          resizable: true
        };
        this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
          cellRendererParams: {
            innerRenderer: function(params) {
              return params.data.employeeName;
            }
          }
        };
        this.rowModelType = "serverSide";
        this.isServerSideGroup = function(dataItem) {
          return dataItem.group;
        };
        this.getServerSideGroupKey = function(dataItem) {
          return dataItem.employeeId;
        };
```

**Expectation:**

All rows and cells (except Group column) should be editable. Example (usual data-tree WITH OUT server side model):

> https://plnkr.co/edit/HCmkdUJ7VPPoug7pOct3?p=preview

```
 this.columnDefs = [{ field: "jobTitle", editable: true }, { field: "employmentType", editable: true }];
```

Pay attention in both cases all columns have 'editable: true'properties and in server side it's not working

**Question:**

What should i do to have a possibilities to edit all rows (even in group rows)?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there - what is missing is `cellEditor` definition for each editable cell, as in example below:

```
{ field: "jobTitle", editable: true, cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor' }
```

Please remember also, that you won't be able to modify directly top level values (grouping is used for), as this will allow you to edit exclusively child nodes of the group.

The list of available ag-grid editors for cells inline modifications:

- agTextCellEditor - applied by default simple text editor
- agPopupTextCellEditor - 'agTextCellEditor' w rapped inpopup
- agLargeTextCellEditor - text popup that for multi-line text
- agSelectCellEditor - dropdown editor
- agPopupSelectCellEditor - 'agSelectCellEditor 'wrapped in popup
- agRichSelectCellEditor - rich select popup that uses row virtualisation, availabe in ag-Grid-Enterprise version

Editing grouped cells is available from version ***Version 7.2.x*** of ag-grid. Property `enableGroupEdit` needs to be set to true to switch on the feature.

```
<ag-grid-angular
      ...
      [enableGroupEdit] = "true"
      ...
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: I add default - 'agTextCellEditor' but editing still not available https://plnkr.co/edit/t1uZ4V3cUs6IHZDsPKYI?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it is - please expand all the grouped rows and double click on 'Job Title' cell from a single row that is not grouped (in your example on the row 'Derek Paul' under 'Erica Rogers' grouping - it works for me).

Comment: yep, but this case (editing not grouper row) works in prev implementation. And how to edit even parent row (row 'Erica Rogers' for example).

Comment: @Yakov Limanskiy - post was updated and your problem solved with new attribute available straight from version Version 7.2.x